# Google Scripts, deleting old files

Tags: file, scripting

I am trying to get this script to work on multiple Google Drive Folders.
Ten send a confirmation email for success or failed
My skills are very limited.
Any assistance would be gratefully received

```
function deleteOldFiles() {
// First Folder
  var df = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID_xxx");
  var arr = new Array();
  var files = df.getFiles();
  while( files.hasNext() ) {
    var f = files.next();
    arr.push( [ [ f.getId() ] , [ f.getLastUpdated() ] ] );
  }
  arr.sort( sortFunction );
  
  for( var i=10 ; i<arr.length ; i++ )
    DriveApp.getFileById( arr[i][0] ).setTrashed( true );
};

function sortFunction( a , b ) {
  var aDate = new Date(a[1]);
  var bDate = new Date(b[1]);
  if ( aDate === bDate ) return 0;
  else if ( aDate < bDate ) return 1;
  else return -1;
};
```